# How to represent internationalized strings in Google-friendly Schema.org

Tags: multilingual, schema.org, json-ld, linked-data, structured-data

Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) doesn't seem to like JSON-LD's [`@language in value object`](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#string-internationalization) approach to string internationalization. For example:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": [{"@language": "ar", "@value": "أياس"},
             {"@language": "en", "@value": "Eyas"}]
}
```

or

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": {"@language": "ar", "@value": "أياس"}
}
```

don't seem to work. I also tried adding `"@type": "Text"` but that doesn't seem to make it happy either.

Is there an accepted way of specifying multiple language representations of the same thing in Schema.org JSON-LD that is respected by search engines?

I know there's `"inLanguage"` for certain types, but that is not general enough to, e.g., work with a `Person`.

Comment: @JayGray I have, but I'm having trouble finding a working solution.

schema.org/Text is a Data Type any property on it. If I'm expressing a Person, there's no way for my to put a schema.org/Language on that object, or associate it with a block of text. At least not that I can find. Posting here to see if I missed anything.

Comment: is your objective: `@Person` knowsLanguage `@Language`? or is it: `@CreativeWork` inLanguage `@Language`?

Comment: My object is finding a way to present `Person.name` in multiple languages/alphabets.

I can list two, `"name": ["Eyas", "إياس"]` but wondering if JSON-LD's native ability to specify the language/local has an equivalent available.

Comment: I just tested your snippets. At first I got an error, but a few tries later, there is no error anymore.

Comment: Ah-- I've just noticed `@language` now works in arrays, but still not in singular values.